# AJAX success function not fetching data from MYSQL database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Apologies for similarities between this post and my previous one. I'd appreciate if someone could help me once again spot where I'm going wrong. Everything else appears to be working fine but what is puzzling me is the 'quiet' response on the AJAX success function. Nothing in the console either.

I've tested the JSON output with the json_encode and print_r functions and got the following - so I presume the JSON string should be ok to work with the AJAX:

```
Array
(
    [proj_start_date] => 2017-04-17
    [proj_end_date] => 2018-04-30
    [wo_nbr_new] => 10002-06
)
{"proj_start_date":"2017-04-17","proj_end_date":"2018-04-30","wo_nbr_new":"10002-06"}
```

Below is the code for the main file:

```
<?php
include 'connect_db.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY proj_nbr";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Add New Work Order</title>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

<h1>Add New Work Order</h1>

<div id="forms-add" name="forms-add">
<form action="add_workorders.php" method="POST">
    <label>Work Order Number (Auto-generated):</label>
    <input type="text" id="wo_nbr" name="wo_nbr"size="8"maxlength="8" value = "" readonly style="float: right"> 
    <br><br>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Project Details</legend>

        <label>Project Number:</label>
        <select  class= "selects" id="proj_nbr" name="proj_nbr" required onchange="">
            <option value="">Select a project </option>
                <?php       
                    if($rowCount>0)
                    {
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                        {
                            echo '<option value="'.
                                $row['proj_id'].'">'.
                                $row['proj_nbr'].
                                ' - '.
                                $row['proj_desc'].
                                ' </option>';                
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<option value="">Project not available</option>';
                    }           
                ?>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <label>Start Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="proj_start_date" name="proj_start_date"size="8"maxlength="8" value = "" readonly style="float: right">
        <br><br>
        <label>End Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="proj_end_date" name="proj_end_date"size="8"maxlength="8" value = "" readonly style="float: right">

    </fieldset>
    <br><br>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" >Save Work Order</button>

    </form>
</div>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test_ajax.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#proj_nbr').change(function()
            {
                var id=$('#proj_nbr').val();
                //alert(id); //this works ok 
                if (id != '')
                {
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: "get_proj_nbrs2.php",
                        method:"POST",
                        data: {id:id}, //data to SEND to PHP file
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        success: function(output) 
                        {
                                console.log(output); //this doesn't return anything in the console??
                                $('#wo_nbr').val(output.wo_nbr_new);
                                $('#proj_start_date').val(output.proj_start_date);
                                $('#proj_end_date').val(output.proj_end_date);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Please select a Project");
                }           
            });
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

And the following is the code in the PHP file:

```
<?php
include 'connect_db.php';

if (isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id']))
{
    $sql2 = "SELECT p.proj_nbr as wo_proj_nbr,p.start_date as proj_start_date,p.end_date as proj_end_date, MAX(w.wo_nbr) AS wo_nbr,
                            CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(MAX(w.wo_nbr),7,2)+1 <= 9 THEN CONCAT(p.proj_nbr,'-0',SUBSTRING(MAX(w.wo_nbr),7,2)+1) 
                            ELSE CONCAT(p.proj_nbr,'-',SUBSTRING(MAX(w.wo_nbr),7,2)+1) END AS wo_nbr_new
                            FROM workorders as w 
                            INNER JOIN projects as p on p.proj_id = w.proj_id
                            WHERE w.proj_id = '".$_POST['id']."'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    {           
        if($result2 ==true)
        {
            $proj_nbr = $row['wo_proj_nbr'];
            $output['proj_start_date'] = $row['proj_start_date'];
            $output['proj_end_date'] = $row['proj_end_date'];               
            if ($row['wo_nbr_new'] != NULL)
            {
                $output['wo_nbr_new'] = $row['wo_nbr_new'];
                echo json_encode($output);
            }
            elseif($row['wo_nbr_new'] == NULL)
            {
                $output['wo_nbr_new'] = $proj_nbr."-01";
                echo json_encode($output);                          
            }
        }
    }
}?>
```

Comment: have you checked the value of id in PHP file?

Comment: i think problem is with your php code. Your are trying to print json in loop which might end up like {"id":5,...}
{"id:4,...} which is not a valid json; and you ajax call is looking json format data.

Comment: Hi Sanjit, I've tried inserting this line just after completing the database connection but I get nothing: echo $_POST['id'];

Comment: Hi Niraj. But I've used a very similar setup previously successfully with a while loop. Also, when I test the results of the PHP file independently, I get just one row. Any suggestion of how I could modify the PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include 'connect_db.php';

if (isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id']))
{
$result = array();
    $sql2 = "SELECT p.proj_nbr as wo_proj_nbr,p.start_date as proj_start_date,p.end_date as proj_end_date, MAX(w.wo_nbr) AS wo_nbr,
                            CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(MAX(w.wo_nbr),7,2)+1 <= 9 THEN CONCAT(p.proj_nbr,'-0',SUBSTRING(MAX(w.wo_nbr),7,2)+1) 
                            ELSE CONCAT(p.proj_nbr,'-',SUBSTRING(MAX(w.wo_nbr),7,2)+1) END AS wo_nbr_new
                            FROM workorders as w 
                            INNER JOIN projects as p on p.proj_id = w.proj_id
                            WHERE w.proj_id = '".$_POST['id']."'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);
if($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    {           

            $proj_nbr = $row['wo_proj_nbr'];
            $output['proj_start_date'] = $row['proj_start_date'];
            $output['proj_end_date'] = $row['proj_end_date'];               
            if ($row['wo_nbr_new'] != NULL)
            {
                $output['wo_nbr_new'] = $row['wo_nbr_new'];

            }
            elseif($row['wo_nbr_new'] == NULL)
            {
                $output['wo_nbr_new'] = $proj_nbr."-01";

            }
           array_push($result,$output);
        }
      echo json_encode($result);
    }
  else
    {
      echo "no rows found";
     }
}?>
```

You was echo each row so you will get result from success function in ajax as each separate sting. so it can't parse. hope this method will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Abhinav. I've tried your suggestions but I'm still not succeeding.

Comment: are you getting the result when you executing the query?

Comment: Yes I get a result when I execute the query from phpmyadmin with some hard coded id(s)

Comment: try put $result2->num_rows > 0   instead of $reult2 == 0 coz $result2 is an object and it wont get inside

Comment: Thanks Abinav. Got it working finally. But didn't need to change to num_rows. But I changed the success function to get the values from a nested JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that you id value is not empty and matches to database field values as well. if so then change the 'id' to 'theid' (might be reserved word) in both the ajax e.g.

```
  data: {theid:id}, //data to SEND to PHP file
```

and in php e.g.

```
if (isset($_POST['theid']) && !empty($_POST['theid'])) {
$sql2 = "SELECT p.proj_nbr as wo_proj_nbr,p.start_date as proj_start_date,p.end_date as proj_end_date, MAX(w.wo_nbr) AS wo_nbr,
                        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(MAX(w.wo_nbr),7,2)+1 <= 9 THEN CONCAT(p.proj_nbr,'-0',SUBSTRING(MAX(w.wo_nbr),7,2)+1) 
                        ELSE CONCAT(p.proj_nbr,'-',SUBSTRING(MAX(w.wo_nbr),7,2)+1) END AS wo_nbr_new
                        FROM workorders as w 
                        INNER JOIN projects as p on p.proj_id = w.proj_id
                        WHERE w.proj_id = '".$_POST['theid']."'";
// code goes here
}
```

Comment: Hi jalalkhan121. When I alert the id in the script, it's not empty. Having said that, I've changed from 'id' to 'theid' as suggested but I'm still not succeeding.

Comment: Hi Albert... seems it's error either in query or record does not exists in database. add this condition before while loop
    if(mysqli_num_rows($row)) { // while loop goes here  } 
    else { echo "no record found"; }

Answer (score 0):

use type at method. method POST depends on jquery version

```
 $.ajax({ 
     url: "get_proj_nbrs2.php",
     type:"POST",
     data: {id:id}, //data to SEND to PHP file
     dataType: "JSON",
     success: function(output) 
     {

     }
 });
```

Comment: Hi Pasunuti. Both type and method work on my jquery version. Thanks for your help though. It's now working.